# C++,ANTLR and VECTORS

Tags: c++, vector, antlr, antlr3

I have an ANTLR rule that would return a vector:

```
main returns [std::vector<int> v]
        :
        ('ERROR' t3=INT{v.push_back(atoi((const char*)$t3.text->chars));}
        '='t4=INT{v.push_back(atoi((const char*)$t4.text->chars));}
        );
```

Then I call it from C++ and try to get the vector data.

However, my problem is that ANTLR3 automatically initialized the vector v to NULL, which isn't allowed and gives me an error.

If I generate the C++ output of antlr and try to compile with my project it gives an error.

I manually went to the parsedfile that ANTLR outputs and removed the setting to NULL option and compiled again and everything worked out.

I can possibly see to solutions to this problem:

1) initializing the vector myself from ANTLR (DONT KNOW HOW TO INITIALIZE VECTORS)

2) Prevent ANTLR from initializing my vector (Not sure if it can be done)

3) Always manually go change the initialization (Not good practice)

4) Find another way to return the vector, tried to return a pointer to array I get the following error:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >’ requested
```

Any help?

Comment: If I'm reading your rule correctly, it looks like you are declaring a vector, then adding data to the vector. Is there any reason that you can't use the fill constructor of the vector template to add the data you want? This will eliminate the problem of having to first instantiate v, then call it directly. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: could you please explain more...

Comment: I think if you use the "@init" to add the numeric representation of t2 and t3 to v, you should be good. Check out "@init" in the ANTLR documentation.

Comment: Which minor version of ANTLR3 are you using?

Comment: not sure. I downloaded the latest one and started a couple of weeks ago. Im on a different system now so can't check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
main returns [std::vector<int> *v]
:
@init { v = new std::vector<int>(); }
( rule content, using *v in actions );
```

ANTLR can then initialize your return value to NULL, which I think it always does.  The @init block creates an empty vector for you to use.

Of course, you will want to actually use a smart pointer like shared_ptr to avoid potential memory leaks as well.

Comment: That is true... worked on it before and forget to update my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize vectors this way:

```
vector<int> a(2,3); //vector a contains 2 elements: 3 and 3
a[0] = 4;//vector a contains 2 elements: 4 and 3
vector<int> b;
b = a;
```

And there are some other ways you can check here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

EDIT:

If you want to initialize with zeros:

```
vector<int> a(2);
```

should do the work, the vector a will contain 2 zeros.

Comment: still this doesn't specify how to initialize it with zero elements